# Get current year's records from a view in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a view called `vwMemberPolicyInfo` and I need to display all records entered in current year.

My query is :

```
select  
    EffectiveDate AS [Month], 
    count(MemberID) AS Agents, 
    sum(ActualPremium) AS Premium
from 
    vwMemberPolicyInfo 
Where 
    EffectiveDate > DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
GROUP BY 
    EffectiveDate
```

but it is not working fine it show result:

```
2010-11-01 00:00:00.000 74  40644.00
2010-07-01 00:00:00.000 86  50418.00

2011-03-08 00:00:00.000 1   744.00
2011-04-08 00:00:00.000 1   0.00
2010-11-02 00:00:00.000 5   2676.00

2011-04-14 00:00:00.000 1   1185.00
2011-02-28 00:00:00.000 7   2988.00

2011-02-23 00:00:00.000 8   8518.00
2011-04-10 00:00:00.000 1   1332.00
2011-04-07 00:00:00.000 3   2544.00
```

I need only the current year entries to display  ..thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

Try `where YEAR(EffectiveDate) = YEAR(GETDATE())`

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes this is working fine ie year(effectivedate)=year(getdate())

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  MONTH(EffectiveDate) AS [Month], 
        count(MemberID) AS Agents, 
        sum(ActualPremium) AS Premium
FROM    vwMemberPolicyInfo 
WHERE   EffectiveDate >= DATEADD(year, YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1, CAST('0001-01-01' AS DATE))
        AND EffectiveDate < DATEADD(year, YEAR(GETDATE()), CAST('0001-01-01' AS DATE))
GROUP BY
        MONTH(EffectiveDate)
```

Comment: +1 For an answer that can use an index (and column statistics) on `EffectiveDate`

Answer (score 1):

It's working just fine - it's doing **exactly** what you told it to - it gives you back all rows that are between today and a year back (e.g. between Apr 15, 2011 and Apr 15, 2010)

What you probably want to achieve is something like this:

```
SELECT
    EffectiveDate AS [Month], 
    COUNT(MemberID) AS Agents, 
    SUM(ActualPremium) AS Premium
FROM
    dbo.vwMemberPolicyInfo 
WHERE
    YEAR(EffectiveDate) = 2011
GROUP BY 
    EffectiveDate
```

This will return **only** rows from the year 2011.

Answer (score 0):

select
    EffectiveDate AS [Month], 
    count(MemberID) AS Agents, 
    sum(ActualPremium) AS Premium
from 
    vwMemberPolicyInfo 
Where 
    dateadd(year,0,EffectiveDate) = DATEADD(year, 0, GETDATE())
GROUP BY 
    EffectiveDate

```
dateadd(year,0,EffectiveDate) = DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
dateadd(year,-1,EffectiveDate) = DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
```